# Making a loop in R for counting word frequencies from specific columns in different tables

Tags: r, loops, dry, unnest

I have 15 different tables, each of which cointains a "text" column with a long text (a series of answers to a poll question). I want to tidy the tables by creating a row for each word in "text" in a column named "word". Then I want to know the word frequencies for each table. I wrote this piece of code:

```
Table1.tidy <- Table1 %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words) %>%
Table1.tidy %>%
  count(word, sort = TRUE)
```

It works fine, but now I'd like to avoid repeating this code for each table. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Put all of your data.frames into a list.

(2) Use `purrr`'s `map` function to apply your workflow:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

my_list <- list(Table1, Table2, Table3)

my_tidy_list <- my_list %>%
  map(~ .x %>%
        unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
        anti_join(stop_words) %>%
#        Table1.tidy %>% # I think this line is a mistake?
        count(word, sort = TRUE))
```

`my_tidy_list[[1]]` returns `Table1.tidy`, `my_tidy_list[[2]]` returns `Table2.tidy` etc.

Comment: Thank you Martin! You're awesome. I failed to mention that the tables are not all numbered from 1 to 15. They are called sth like Table1, Table1a, Table2, Table2a, Table2b, Table3, etc. I need to keep those names because they correspond to specific series of answers on questions in the dataset. But I solved that by naming them: `names(my_list) <- c("Table1", "Table1a", etc)`